# Looking for Comet-Style server or client

Tags: c#, comet, long-polling

I'm looking for a good and simple way to notify my clients about some events in a "push"-way, just like the Comet/Long-Polling server do.

The main idea was to set-up a server and create an app with C# which will act as a client.

I've found a good thing, Comet server (currently NGINX with http_push module). But as i've got from other user experience, it's not that good for external apps (C, C++, C#, other), it's just was think to push messages on the web (or I'm wrong there?).

So, I 'm looking for a good way how to notify clients in that way, or may be someone knows good client/library in C# for a Comet-Style client?

Thanks!

Comment: Comet is used to get around **BROWSERS** being unable to query servers. If you are making a server-client, just open a connection and get full 2 way communications...

Comment: But looking at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742631/c-httpwebresponse-comet-problem, TS has got the stream using C#, somehow.

I'm now trying to create server-client, i'm just trying to implement a client to use with Nginx http_push module (http://pushmodule.slact.net/).

Which system does Twitter use to push the user statuses?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx

It implements both client and server in c# (ASP.NET for server)

Comment: Will see into it, but ont the first view, there is nothing about the client.

Comment: The client is a browser, or simple code to make a request. The code does not respond to the request until there is something to return or a timeout occurs. This is what comet is about!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync). It's got client implementations in a bunch of languages, one of which is (naturally) c#.